# Как рассчитать необходимую ширину и высоту двух изображений?

Tags: android, алгоритм, imageview

Есть `tableRow`, в него помещаются два `ImageView`. В `ImageView` загружаются фотографии различных размеров. Необходимо изменить масштаб каждой фотографии (подогнать под одну высоту) (пример ниже)
[image: Пример]

На одном из тематических сайтов подсказали следующие:

```
k1 = W / ( w2 * ( h1/h2 + w1/w2))
k2 = k1 * (h1/h2)
k2 = k1 * (h1/h2)
k1 * h1 = k2 * h2 //--Находим общую высоту--//
newW1 = k1 * w1; newW2 = k2 * w2 //--Находим широты--//
где - W - ширина экрана, k1 и k2 коэф. масшт. первого и второго изображения, w1, h1 и w2, h2 - оригинальная (ту, которую загружаем) ширина и высота первого и второго изображения соответственно
```

В итоге получаю:

[image: 1]

Результат расчета:

```
D/TEST: IMAGE SIZE 1: 135.0  x  807.0
D/TEST: IMAGE SIZE 2: 807.0  x  605.0
D/TEST: K1 IMAGE 1: 0.8914977
D/TEST: K2 IMAGE 2: 1.1891547
D/TEST: NEW SIZE IMAGE 1: 120.35219  x  719.4386
D/TEST: NEW SIZE IMAGE 2: 959.6479  x  719.4386
```

[image: 2]

Результат расчета:

```
D/TEST: IMAGE SIZE 1: 807.0  x  605.0
D/TEST: IMAGE SIZE 2: 807.0  x  453.0
D/TEST: K1 IMAGE 1: 0.57301074
D/TEST: K2 IMAGE 2: 0.7652793
D/TEST: NEW SIZE IMAGE 1: 462.41968  x  346.6715
D/TEST: NEW SIZE IMAGE 2: 617.5804  x  346.6715
```

Где красным цветом - остаток `imageView`. Как видно на втором примере высота получается не верная (да и ширина то же). Свойство `imageView scaleType.CenterCrop` использовать не хочу (как идеал масштабирования беру клиент ВК, с ним все визуально и смерял).

Верстка `imageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/item_image_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
```

По скольку с математикой у меня все плохо, ума не приложу как разместить два изображения пропорционально (клиент ВК беру за идеал).

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: Пробовали `weight`? Попробуйте указать одинаковый вес у обоих `imageview`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h1 - высота первой картинки
w1 - ширина первой картинки
h2 - высота второй картинки
w2 - ширина второй картинки

scale = Math.max(h1, h2);

image1.setWidth((scale/h1)*w1)
image11.setHeight((scale/h1)*h1)

image12.setWidth((scale/h2)*w2)
image12.setHeight((scale/h2)*h2)

Comment: Спасибо, работает, немного подкорректировал: `TableRow.LayoutParams image1Params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                        (int) testWidth1, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, testWidth1); itemImage1.setLayoutParams(image1Params);`