# Найти ширину и высоту трех изображений

Tags: android, алгоритм, математика

Есть `tableRow`, в него помещаются три `ImageView`. В `ImageView` загружаются фотографии различных размеров. Необходимо изменить масштаб каждой фотографии (подогнать под одну высоту).

Тут же задавал вопрос по поводу двух изображений ([ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688688/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)) - все прекрасно работает, (комбинация из варианта в вопросе + отмеченный ответ), но так, как с математикой имею определенные проблемы - сделать то же самое но с тремя изображениями я не в состоянии.

Привожу алгоритм из моего первого вопроса:

```
k1 = W / ( w2 * ( h1/h2 + w1/w2))
k2 = k1 * (h1/h2)
k2 = k1 * (h1/h2)
k1 * h1 = k2 * h2 //--Находим общую высоту--//
newW1 = k1 * w1; newW2 = k2 * w2 //--Находим широты--//
где - W - ширина экрана, k1 и k2 коэф. масшт. первого и второго изображения, w1, h1 и w2, h2 - оригинальная (ту, которую загружаем) ширина и высота первого и второго изображения соответственно`
```

А так же то, что имею в итоге:

```
float image1Width = Utils.getDownloadedImageWidth(post, indexImage1);
float image2Width = Utils.getDownloadedImageWidth(post, indexImage2);
float image1Height = Utils.getDownloadedImageHeight(post, indexImage1);
float image2Height = Utils.getDownloadedImageHeight(post, indexImage2);
float scale = Math.max(image1Height, image2Height);
float newImage1Width = (scale / image1Height) * image1Width;
float newImage2Width = (scale / image2Height) * image2Width;
float k1 = MainActivity.SCREEN_WIDTH / (image2Width * (image1Height / image2Height + image1Width / image2Width));
float k2 = k1 * (image1Height / image2Height);
float tempHeight1 = k1 * image1Height;
float tempHeight2 = k2 * image2Height;
float tempHeight = Math.max(tempHeight1, tempHeight2);`
```

Как все таки данный алгоритм переделать для трех изображений?

Answer (score 2):

h1 - высота первой картинки 
w1 - ширина первой картинки 
h2 - высота второй картинки 
w2 - ширина второй картинки
h3 - высота третьей картинки 
w3 - ширина третьей картинки

scale = Math.max(h1, h2);
scale = Math.max(scale, h3);

w1 = (scale/h1)*w1;
w2 = (scale/h2)*w2;
w3 = (scale/h3)*w3;

h1=h2=h3=scale;